# Intermittent "Socket closed" exception with HttpUrlConnection

Tags: java, sockets, httpurlconnection

I have a servlet application running under jboss 7.1.1/java 1.7 that sends http requests to another server. Everything works fine for most of the time, but occasionally (from one to a couple of times a day) we get a “Socket closed” exception.  I’ve been trying to find out what might be causing this but so far I’ve been unsuccessful. By the way, this has been happening while the application was running under older versions of Jboss/Java so the versions might not be that relevant.

Here’s an excerpt from the method where this happens:

. . . . .

```
try

{

    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlEndpoint.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=UTF-8");
    conn.setRequestProperty("charset", "UTF-8");
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
    out.write(env.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    InputStream iss = null;
    conn.connect();
try
{
    iss = conn.getInputStream(); // this is where the exception is caught
```

. . . . . .

And here’s what the exception looks like:

. . . . . .

```
java.net.SocketException: socket closed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:633)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:579)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1322)
```

. . . . . .

I came across some posts that were mentioning the sockets pool the http connection is keeping, but I’m not sure whether and how this can help me solve the problem I have.

I’ve now exhausted all the ideas I had and I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: You might try disabling [http keepalive](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/http-keepalive.html). HTTP itself has a race condition, i.e. the server might timeout a persistent connection after a while, and if you happen to send a request over that existing TCP connection just as that connection is timed out on the server, you'll get the results you have here.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I'll certainly try that. 
Two questions though:
1. Is there a way to check that indeed this is what is happening 
2. If indeed the keepalive property is at the root of the problem - in what circumstances should one NOT use it

Comment: I have some theories, but here's some general guidance. In designing a robust system, you have to expect that the HTTP requests are going to fail intermittently. Even if your server has 100% uptime, uncontrollable stuff can happen on the network between your client code and the server. Hence, you should design your client code to expect an IOException and do appropriate retry logic.

Comment: I know that comment above of mine isn't really an answer to your specific and well-formed question. I'm just trying to emphasize not getting hung up over the root cause, but instead be prepared for anything with regards to network. Also the answer EJP gave below is good.

Comment: And now to actually provide an answer. What EJP said. Also, the closing of the request stream (`out.close()`) likely signals a one-way socket shutdown under the hood. It might be better to use a Content-Length header instead of closing the input stream. That's only a hypothesis as a cause of a race condition.

Answer (score 1):

It would make more sense to call `conn.connect()` *before* doing any I/O. It doesn't make any sense at all to do it afterwards. You don't need to close the output stream.

Comment: EJP, could you just elaborate a bit more what the effect of calling conn.connect() before conn.getOutputStream() in this case would be?

Comment: Oh please. *Surely* it is obvious that writing to the output stream cannot actually take place unless the connection object is connected? In which case clearly it must auto-connect itself? In which case calling connect() after the output steps must be redundant? And therefore pointless? And senseless?

Comment: I wasn't trying to get into an argument - I just wanted to understand how the whole thing works under the bonnet as it's not that obvious to me.
Anyway, I did add a conn.connect() before sending the request and run my test case which emulates what happens in production and after a couple of iterations it threw "Socket closed" again. So opening the connection explicitly did not solve the main issue.